# How do I suspend layout drawing?

Tags: android, layout, resume, suspend

Under .NET you can call SuspendLayout() / ResumeLayout().

Is there an equivalent under Android?

My reason is this... I have a RelativeLayout that contains upto 64 "panels" (another RelativeLayout with 3 TextView children).

Via a serial comms link, I get an XML message describing the number of panels to display, what their size is, and what to place in the 3 text views in each visible panel.

The initial code all works and I can display a page of panels.

However when I get a new XML message, I hide all the panels, re-position those defined in the new XML message, update the 3 text views per panel, and then show the in-use panels.

Again, this works, but the page goes blank (for maybe 1-2 seconds) when all the panels are hidden, and then all the new panels appear.

I'm guessing that hiding/showing the panels is a relatively quick process, but decoding the XML and updating the panel text/font/colour/etc takes a while to compute before the panels get re-enabled.

I'd like to know how to "suspend" the drawing process while I update the top-level RelativeLayout, and then "resume" the draw when all the views have been initialised.

Is there a way to do this?

Or am I approaching this whole thing from the wrong angle?
If so, what's the best method to try?

--- UPDATE ---

Okay, seems I was a bit premature as I found a "quirk" in my code that caused the 1-2 second delay (an un-handled XML message).

But thanks for taking the time to give me some pointers.  A bit of light reading when I'm bored!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is figure out how much work you can can delegate to a background thread (e.g., "decoding the XML"). You can then safely update the UI by using `Looper.getMainLooper()`.

It would probably be better to inflate and populate new layouts, then swap them, rather than updating the visible ones.  You could then have a set of views you recycle, i.e., maintain twice as many as you have on display.  This is exactly the point of [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) (see also ["Creating a List with RecyclerView"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)).

[Live data](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) may also be worthwhile for you to look into.